# htaccess help in coexisting Codeigniter and Wordpress install

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

My intention here is to have a codeigniter app with a blog under the same domain. The admin for both should be separate.

The directory structure is this:

```
httpdocs/.htaccess
httpdocs/application/ <== CI installation
httpdocs/blog/        <== WP installation
httpdocs/blog/.htaccess
```

URLs would be like this:

```
mysite.com         <== CI
mysite.com/tools   <== CI
mysite.com/forum   <== CI
mysite.com/blog    <== WP
```

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.andyhawthorne.net/2011/07/using-codeigniter-and-wordpress-together/) to set up and it worked nicely.

Both my codeigniter app and WP ***blog home page*** show exactly as they should, with correct URLs, styles etc.

I can also access ***mysite.com/blog/wp-admin*** normally for WP back end stuff.

My issue is when I try to access an actual blog post, for example:

```
mysite.com/blog/fiction/what-is-going-on/
```

When I do this, I get ***Codeigniter's 404 error page***.

My root .htaccess (httpdocs/.htaccess) is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|blog|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My blog .htaccess (httpdocs/blog/.htaccess) is this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Will post more info if requested. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK the solution is to use

CI .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and

WP .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

That did the trick. Now all pages show without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use 2 sets of conditions on the CI `.htaccess` (one on the root folder)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This will allow the processing of blog URLs first and then deal with the CI URLs. You need to be careful not to have any controllers or routes using the term `blog` in your application.

Comment: thx @dakdad but it's not working - I still get CI's 404 page for blog posts - any other ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: @dakdad What if you need to use "blog" in your controller as we run blogs for our users?

Comment: @Stefan same uri cannot serve 2 things, one of them needs to be different.

Comment: @sakdad Could this not be a Htaccess rewrite rule and detect if the host is the blog and not a users blog which is on a subdomain or custom domain?

Answer (score 0):

I would try three things in your Wordpress .htaccess (don't touch the CI one -- it looks correct):

First, try removing the forward slash from before your index.php:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If that doesn't work, then instead, try setting the RewriteBase to /blog/:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Finally, if neither of those things work, you can try manually adding "/blog/" to your index.php line at the end:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: any reason to use your code instead of my answer above? mine seems to work fine, but I wonder if you have any opinion on how I put it together and if there's any advantage to your solution