# CodeIgniter and Wordpress integration .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a CodeIgniter installation in within a sub directory I have a WordPress installation so my directory structure looks like this

```
-- application
-- blog
-- system
-- .htaccess
-- index.php
```

So that requests to the wordpress site don't get routed through the CodeIgniter index.php I have the following in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(assets|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|blog)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This worked fine locally on my server.  But I recently moved over to a new VPS and now this rule isn't working.  Any requests to www.domain.com/blog are getting the CodeIgniter 404.

So it's like my `RewriteCond` isn't capturing the requests.  Can anything thing of something that might cause this to stop working or anything I should check?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263812/htaccess-help-in-coexisting-codeigniter-and-wordpress-install)

Comment: Yeah I tried the answers in that question but to no avail

Comment: For test sake, try w/o question mark in last line. I have it without on digitalocean VPS droplet.

Comment: Hm that didn't work either but appreciate the help